# Data is not binding with backend

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

Data is not binding in the controller side, I am posting data using angularjs httppost, which is not binding with the DTO in in the controller.

Here is my angularjs code:

```
$http.post(ctxPath + 'sampleUrl', dataObject, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p'
    }
}).then(function (res) {
    alert(res);
});
```

My backend Code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "sampleUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public @ResponseBody
BaseResponse createOrUpdate(
        SomeDTO someDTO,
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

        }
```

Here is the browser out put:

[image]

Data is not binding with DTO's in controller, all variables are coming as nulls, what went the wronghere?

Comment: i am not getting any errors, but the values are not getting found in the request

Comment: I notice you're using a content type of `multipart/form-data`. Are you trying to upload a file?

Comment: How would a **multi** part request be mapped to a **single** normal object?

Comment: @WillKeeling, yes i am trying to upload file with other data

Comment: @zeroflagL, that is pogo class contains commonmultipart object

Comment: It doesn't matter what the class contains, it **IS** not a multipart object. Nor is it annotated with `@RequestPart`, so that Spring could at least map one part of the request.